# How to notify my users when app is closed by using SSE?

Tags: server-sent-events

I have a simple question about SSE. I know that SSE allows me to send notifications when users is connecting to my website. But let's assume that he is not connected for one month. I want him to receive all notifications he missed. How to do that ? Do I have to save all unread notifications in a database and delete the notification from this database only when the user click the notification or there is a simpler solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must send a unique id by starting your message with "id". If your connection is broken and start again, the client will send a special http header with last id (Last-Event-ID).
It works for diconnections limited in time but for one month, I think you must use a cache/database to store messages because your server can restart and will lose your events.